# $locationChangeStart doesn't call but it called earlier

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would be want to call preventDefault event when someone change state.

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', (e) => {
  if (!$window.confirm("Are you sure leave this page?")) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

It doesn't work when i try to leave page.

It works if i use $rootScope.

When i use `$rootScope.$on` `event.preventDefault` doesn't work.

How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: which version of ui-router you are using?

Comment: @Rachmaninoff, hi, thanks for your answer. We use v1.0.11

Comment: If you have still problem I can give you a solution based on `promise` and a confirm modal.

Comment: @Rachmaninoff, yes, i would be very happy to see some example :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a transition hook inside a run block:

```
run(function($transitions) {
    $transitions.onBefore({}, function() {
        function confirmDialog(msg) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                let confirmed = window.confirm(msg);
                return confirmed ? resolve(true) : reject(false);
            });
        }
    })
});
```

for more info take a look at these links:
https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks#promises
http://vancelucas.com/blog/using-window-confirm-as-a-promise/